# Reveal website-content when facebook-page liked

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-like

I'm trying to reveal content on my website only to people who like my facebook page. I've tried severall tutorials but none of them work. The closest I got was following this:

http://www.dejanlevec.com/2011/05/11/how-to-display-certain-page-content-only-to-users-who-have-liked-our-page-on-facebook/

I can get it to work if I first dislike the page and then like it on the facebook_test.php . Thus it doesn't detect if I already like the page.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this with javascript before using FB.Event.subscribe and edge.create as described below:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'APP_ID_HERE', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
  function (response) {
     window.location = "http://redirectexamplehere.com";
  });
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
function (response) {
  window.location = "http://redirectexamplehere.com";
});

  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
//]]>
</script>
```

This way a user will be redirected to wherever you specify upon them liking the page. Remember to load the SDK first or it won't work.

Comment: But will this work on my own website? It has no code to say which page the visitor has to like?

Comment: Yes it will, put this on your index, or the page the user will land on. Basically with this one, it will work whenever anyone pressed the like button that is on that page. It can also be made to use other features, like it will not go to next page until user makes a comment, ect...

Answer (score 0):

Detecting if a user likes you on a website is a bit trickier than in a Facebook page.  You'll need to setup a Facebook application and use that on your website and have the user authenticate using the app in addition to liking your page.  Once you have that connection with the user you can test to see if they are logged in and have liked your page.  At that point you can display different types of content.

The extra step of having to authenticate the user is probably why you don't see this implemented on too many websites.